# Extra space when using asp.net form tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am trying to use the following example in my asp.net page:

[https://googlesamples.github.io/web-fundamentals/samples/layouts/navigation-patterns/appbar-navdrawer-bottombar-sample.html#](https://googlesamples.github.io/web-fundamentals/samples/layouts/navigation-patterns/appbar-navdrawer-bottombar-sample.html)

Everything is fine except there is a blank space at the top of the page when the links are opened. You can see the area I am referring to selected in red below:

[image: error image].

If I remove the form tag:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
</form>
```

Then it is ok:

[image: correct image]

Does anyone know why the extra space is being created and how to get rid of it?  I tried adding margin-top:0 as follows (also tried margin-bottom):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="margin-top:0;"></form>
```

And that did not help.  Two notes:

- Browser used for testing: Chrome.
- There is no code inside the form tag.  All the code from the sample is before and outside of the form tags.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the form this CSS:

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:inline;
```

Comment: Thanks tried it but It still shows the same space mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and this worked for me:

```
html, body, form {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Tested on Chrome, FF & IE and seems to do the trick.